# How to get phone number of the person I'm dialing

Tags: android

in Android, I need to get the phone number of the person I'm dialing to in my BroadcastReceiver (OFFHOOK state)

I know I can get the INCOMING number but I need the outgoing, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

See http://code.google.com/p/unlocking-android/source/browse/chapter7/trunk/src/com/msi/manning/telephonyexplorer/OutgoingCallReceiver.java?spec=svn78&r=78

Comment: That doesn't work to me, the intent action received is PHONE_STATE not NEW_OUTGOING_CALL, I'm developing on android 2.2+

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve this from a Broadcast in response to ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL:

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Try to read the phone number from previous receivers.
    String phoneNumber = getResultData();

    if (phoneNumber == null) {
      // We could not find any previous data. Use the original phone number in this case.
      phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
    }

  }
}
```

It is important to use getResultData as you [may not be the only broadcast receiver](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/01/processing-ordered-broadcasts.html) processing the phone number.

Comment: That doesn't really work, are you sure this can be done on Android 2.2+?

Comment: @AhmedSoliman Absolutely, the [blog post linked](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/01/processing-ordered-broadcasts.html) was written by a Google engineer who has published this code in his own [open source](https://code.google.com/p/right-number/) app.